# Removing slash from web api JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, getjson

I have a WEB API C#, inside it I have Data which is a link, for example: `images/Chinese/AbaloneEggCustard.jpg`

but in JSON, it appear like this:

```
[{"BackgroundImage":"images\/Chinese\/AbaloneEggCustard.jpg", ......}]
```

May I know how can I remove the slash? Need it remove so hopefully I can access the images when I link with azure.

---

Here's my controller codes:

```
public IEnumerable<Food> Get()
    {
        List<Food> Cases = new List<Food>();
        try
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HealthyFoodDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            myConnection.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT * from [Recipe] ";

            myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection);
            myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (myDataReader.Read())
            {
                Cases.Add(new Food()
                {
                    RecipeID = (int)myDataReader["RecipeID"],
                    RecipeTitle = (string)myDataReader["RecipeTitle"],
                    FoodCategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(myDataReader["FoodCategoryId"]),
                    Serves = (string)myDataReader["Serves"],
                    PerServing = (string)myDataReader["PerServing"],
                    Favourite = ((Convert.ToInt32(myDataReader["Favourite"]) == 1) ? true : false),
                    Directions = (string)myDataReader["Directions"],
                    BackgroundImage = (string)myDataReader["BackgroundImage"],
                    HealthyTips = (string)myDataReader["HealthyTips"],
                    Nutritions = (string)myDataReader["Nutritions"],
                    Ingredients = (string)myDataReader["Ingredients"]
                });
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myConnection != null)
                myConnection.Close();
        }
        return Cases;
    }
```

here's my Index.cshtml code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Send an AJAX request
        $.getJSON("api/food/",
        function (data) {
            // on success, 'data' contains a list of products
            $.each(data, function (key, val){

                //format the text to display
                var str = val.RecipeTitle + ' | ' + val.FoodCategoryID + ' | ' + val.Serves + ' | ' + val.PerServing + ' | ' + val.Favourites + ' | ' + val.Directions + ' | ' + val.BackgroundImage + ' | ' + val.HealthyTips + ' | ' + val.Nutritions + ' | ' + val.Ingredients;

                // add a list item for the product
                $('<li/>', { html: str }).appendTo($('#cases'));

            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: which backslash are your referring to?

Comment: back slash = \
slash = /

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're calling the API, and getting back the normally escaped JSON object:

```
var myObject = Foo.API.Call(); //returns object with BackgroundImage property.
```

If you're saving the result to a text file, you can use `JavaScriptSerializer`:

```
var bg = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(myObject);
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\foo.txt"))
{
    writer.Write(bg.BackgroundImage);
}
```

The text file saved should be the unescaped string.

Comment: but if I want to show in JSON without backslash which is this \, how am I suppose to do? Is it got to do with getjson?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question, didn't see any backslashes in the original post. `/` needs to be escaped in JavaScript and JSON, so the leading ``\`` is required, but will go away when you deserialize back into a CLR object or will be properly interpreted as a JSON object.

Comment: So how am I going to deal with \ because if I save as a text file still have \ . Or there's no way?

Comment: Updated answer. You'll need to deserialize the API response to unescape the string if you're trying to write it to a file.

Comment: Hello sorry for this late reply, I just update my question with my getAPI codes. So I'm not sure whether your code can be implemented to my code or not.

Comment: In your new code, I don't see where you're getting JSON data? Are you serializing the return object? If so, you'll need to deserialize on the API clients' side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
string deserializedString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(serializedString);
```